# For each odd item in php array

Tags: php

I am trying to print every 2nd item or an array starting with 1 so the 1st, 3rd, 5th element etc. My current code give illegal offset type error

```
$array2 = array(explode(',', $prodorder));

<?php foreach($array2 as $value) { 
    if ($value % 205 !== 0) {

        $productscore =  $_POST[$value];
        echo $value;
?>

    <tr><td><?php echo $productname;?></td><td><?php    echo $productdescription;?></td></tr>

    <?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop instead.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($items); $i+=2)
    echo $items[$i] . '<br>';
```

Comment: I have changed to the above but this isn't echoing out anything. My array values are 1,2,4,9 and I am expecting 1 and 4 to be echoed

Answer (score 0):

This will also work, but using `for` loop is better and more elegant way.

```
$array2 = [
  "value1",
  "value2",
  "value3",
  "value4",
  "value5"  
];  
//$array2 = array_values($array2);

foreach($array2 as $k => $v) { 
   if (($k + 1) % 2 == 1) {   
       echo $v;
   }  
}
```

Also this cant be used in associative array, unless you use `array_values`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($array2 as $k=>$value) { 
    if ($k % 2 !== 0) {
        $productscore =  $_POST[$value];
        echo $value;
    }
}
```